# ¿Cómo obtener solo los registros (en mysql) de una tabla que todos sus registros en otra tabla relacionada tengan una columna con un mismo valor?

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener solo los registros de una tabla que todos sus registros en otra tabla relacionada tengan una columna con un mismo valor.

Tengo una tabla padre **parent_table**:

```
| Id    | name        |
|:------|:-----------:|
| 1     | registro ab |
| 2     | registro b  |
| 3     | registro bx |
| 4     | registro yz |
```

Tengo una tabla hija relacionada a la tabla padre **child_table**:

```
| Id    | parent_table_id | approved |
|:------|:---------------:|:--------:|
| 1     | 1               | 1        |
| 2     | 1               | 1        |
| 3     | 1               | 1        |
| 5     | 1               | 0        |
|:------|:---------------:|:--------:|
| 6     | 2               | 1        |
| 7     | 2               | 1        |
| 8     | 2               | 1        |
| 9     | 2               | 1        |
|:------|:---------------:|:--------:|
| 10    | 3               | 1        |
| 11    | 3               | 1        |
| 12    | 3               | 1        |
| 13    | 3               | 1        |
|:------|:---------------:|:--------:|
| 14    | 4               | 0        |
| 15    | 4               | 1        |
| 16    | 4               | 1        |
| 17    | 4               | 1        |
```

Caso 1: no se obtienen los registros de la tabla **parent_table** con id 1 ni el id 4 ya que no todos los registros dentro de la tabla **child_table** tienen la columna approved con valor 1;

Caso 1: sí se obtienen los registros de la tabla **parent_table** con id 2 y id 3 ya que todos los registros dentro de la tabla **child_table** tienen la columna approved con valor 1;

Probé con este código, pero en algunos casos funciona, en otros no:

```
SELECT distinct parent_table.id FROM parent_table WHERE exists 
( SELECT * FROM child_table GROUP BY child_table.id HAVING child_table.approved=1 )
```

Su ayuda será muy importante, gracias de antemano.

Dios bendiga a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table
  WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent_table_id
      FROM child_table
      WHERE approved=0  
  ) AND Id IN (
    SELECT parent_table_id
      FROM child_table
  );

+----+-------------+
| Id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  2 | registro b  |
|  3 | registro bx |
+----+-------------+
```

No te hace falta agrupar, con que detectes aquellos que tenga un `approved=0` y los excluyas, ya habrás conseguido tu objetivo.

Aporto el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE child_table(
  Id int,
  parent_table_id int,
  approved bool,
  FOREIGN KEY(parent_table_id)
    REFERENCES parent_table(Id)
  );
INSERT INTO parent_table (`name`) VALUES
  ('registro ab'),
  ('registro b'),
  ('registro bx'),
  ('registro yz');
INSERT INTO child_table (Id,parent_table_id,approved) VALUES
  (1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(5,1,0),(6,2,1),(7,2,1),
  (8,2,1),(9,2,1),(10,3,1),(11,3,1),(12,3,1),
  (13,3,1),(14,4,0),(15,4,1),(16,4,1),(17,4,1);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta sí funciona con el dataset que comentaste, pero para las tablas reales que tengo no. Estoy usando laravel 8 para generar las migraciones.

Comment: Si hay registros en la tabla padre que no tengan registros en la tabla hija, la consulta que comentas también trae esos registros de la tabla padre.

Comment: SELECT * FROM parent_table
  WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent_table_id
      FROM child_table
      WHERE approved=0  
  ) AND exists (
  SELECT id, parent_table_id FROM child_table WHERE parent_table.id = child_table.parent_table_id
  );
Le agregué una condicional más para obtener solo los que tengan registros en la tabla hija, ya con eso funcionó, gracias David.

Comment: Ok, modifico la respuesta incluyendo esta condición. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)